# Growth Rate Of Primeth Recurrence (A$007097$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I was looking through the OEIS, and I noticed something interesting about [A007097](https://oeis.org/A007097) ($a_1=2$, $a_{n+1}=p_{a_{n}}$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime)- it seems to grow superexponentially, which is something I'm not used to interacting with, in or out of school. I'm not sure exactly what form such a function would take, though. My best guess from a lot of fiddling around on Desmos is that it's approximately $x^{\frac{4}{15}(x\ln(x)-1)}$, but I don't know if there's a nicer form for this approximation, how close it is to being correct, or what might be correct if this is on the wrong track.

So my question is:

> What is the asymptotic growth rate of A$007097$? Or what is $O(\text{A}007097)$?

I do know that the $n$th prime is approximately $n\ln(n)$, but I'm not certain if there's a good way to apply that fact to this particular problem. Any suggestions you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems difficult to extend the given table.

Using the given values, a quick and dirty regression for
$$\log(a_n)= \alpha~ n^\beta$$ gives $(R^2=0.999535)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha & 0.149758 & 0.010088 & \{0.128778,0.170737\} \\
 \beta & 1.884506 & 0.022487 & \{1.837742,1.931269\} \\
\end{array}$$
which, more than likely, hides some logarithmic contribution.

Comment: It seems to me that a premise of your answer is that there is not (or at least, does not appear to be) any "nice", analytically determinable closed form for an asymptotic growth rate. Is that the case? That would be disappointing, but c'est la vie.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp. If you compare with most sequences in OEIS, you can notice that this one does not contain many comments

Comment: I'm not certain what that response means. Are you saying the sequence is insufficiently interesting or well-studied to *have* an analytically determinable closed form for an asymptotic growth rate? As opposed to having a *known* closed form?